# Can the Apple Watch be Worn While Bathing?

Tags: apple-watch, watchos

Can you wear the Apple Watch during bath time? What is it's resistant to both water and soap?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use it in the shower because it is waterproof for 30 minutes at a maximum depth of 1 metre and soap won't affect it just don't use REALLY hot water or you might overheat the watch and plastics/rubber

Comment: What a splendid idea! You are really useful!

Answer (score 2):

[The Apple Watch is splash and water *resistant*, not waterproof.](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT205000) Although it would likely survive a quick dip, long submersion isn't recommended and could kill your watch. If you want to wear it in the tub while playing with your favorite toys, you can (even though Apple says not to), but keep it above water. You're to probably better off keeping it away from water though, especially if your watch and corresponding band gets sudsy.

Comment: That is correct if you have the Apple Watch series 1